# Dealing with dates in js - there must be an easier way?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to do something for the past hours that really should be easier. (It's the easiest thing in the world with my beloved PHP..... but I need it in JS.) 
All I need to do is to output various dates relative to the present date (all in YYYY-mm-dd) ....

var today = TODAY'S DATE

var tomorrow = TOMORROW'S DATE

var end_of_this_week = DATE OF THE FINAL DAY (SUNDAY) OF THE CURRENT WEEK

var start_of_next_week = DATE OF THE FIRST DAY (MONDAY) OF NEXT WEEK

var end_of_this_month = DATE OF THE FINAL DAY OF THE CURRENT MONTH

var start_of_next_month = DATE OF THE FIRST DAY OF NEXT MONTH

var end_of_next_month = DATE OF THE FINAL DAY OF NEXT MONTH

That's it. I know about the 'Datejs' package but (no offence) I found it to be a big mess. I've poured over this (and other) forums looking for an answer to this, and while there are a few useful bits and pieces around, I ended up with more bugs (e.g. 13 months in a year) than anything else. I think that if someone with the know-how could come up with an elegant solution, it would be very useful for lots of people.

Here is the foundation from which all of this stuff may be derived:

```
    var date_default = new Date(new Date().getTime());
    var day_now = date_default.getDate();
    var month_now = date_default.getMonth()+1;
    var year_now = date_default.getFullYear();

    var today = year_now+'-'+month_now+'-'+day_now;
```

Comment: Look at Moment.js.

Comment: `new Date(new Date().getTime())` is exactly the same as `new Date()`

Comment: There really isn't, dates are complicated, but there are libraries, like Moment, that simplify things.

Comment: Read this gem: FalsehoodsAboutTime.com ;)

Comment: Thomas Kleßen: :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/) to be the cleanest library for dealing with date and time manipulation in js.

e.g for your `tomorrow` you could do:

```
const tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days').format('YY-MMM-dd');
```

Docs here : [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: Yes, it looks really great! I hadn't come across it until now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to obtain the values you need although, as mentioned, this isn't straightforward with vanilla JS. For example,

```
var today = new Date();

var tomorrow = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+ 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

These are few libraries that you might be interested in:

- [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) - http://momentjs.com
- [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) - https://date-fns.org
- [joda](https://github.com/js-joda/js-joda) - https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/
- [Datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) - http://datejs.com/
- [FormatJS](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js) -https://formatjs.io/github/ and
- [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon) - https://moment.github.io/luxon/